# How to set ytics in gnuplot for a minus to plus scale

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot some two column data in x-y format. X-axis is in log scale while Y-axis ordinary scale and range from -1 to 1, i.e. set yrange [-1:1].
I could not set ytics as -1:0.2:1. 
I am getting an error that increment must be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in `help xtics`, "start, increment, end" uses comma as the separator, not colon.

```
set ytics -1, 0.2, 1
```

Comment: I am sorry for such a silly mistake. I later realised that I should use in this way. Thank you Choroba for the reply.